# Pure CSS3 Slide Menu - Content Jumps to Top on Slide

Tags: html, css

I have been working on a pure css slide menu..

Basically setting the Nav Menu position:fixed top:0 right:-200.. using radio buttons to control the slide

```
<input type="radio" id="nav-expand" name="nav" />
<input type="radio" id="nav-collapse" name="nav" checked="checked" />
<header>
    <div class="logo">
        <h1>Header Text</h1>
    </div>
    <label for="nav-expand" class="btn-nav-expand">
        <span class="top"></span>
        <span class="middle"></span>
        <span class="bottom"></span>
    </label>
    <label for="nav-collapse" class="btn-nav-collapse">
        <span class="top"></span>
        <span class="middle"></span>
        <span class="bottom"></span>
    </label>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a data-title="Home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a data-title="News">News</a></li>
            <li><a data-title="Out People">Our People</a></li>
            <li><a data-title="About Us">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a data-title="Product and Services">Product and Services</a></li>
            <li><a data-title="Case Studies">Case Studies</a></li>
            <li><a data-title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <label for="nav-collapse" class="overlay"></label>
</header>
```

On click using translatex(-200px) moves the body content and brings in the menu..

Only problem is content, it doesn’t matter how far the content is scrolled down the page, the content will jump back to the top..

Ultimately I want the content to stay exactly where it was, in case the user will cancel the menu and continue to read..

Here is a Pen showing the problem.. scroll the main content and then open menu.. [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbRpJv) .. it will always reset the content jumping back to the top..

The other issue, when the menu is visible, if you scroll on the menu part, it will scroll the main content, not the menu..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem..

It was due to the position of the two radio buttons.. adding visibility: hidden; to each radio button has resolved the problem..

```
    <input type="radio" id="nav-expand" name="nav" />
    <input type="radio" id="nav-collapse" name="nav" checked="checked" />

    #nav-expand,
    #nav-collapse {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
```

New [Code Pen](http://codepen.io/chameleon95/pen/yYWyjB) with revised CSS..

This has not resolved the other issue.. when the menu is visible, if you scroll on the menu part, it will scroll the main content, not the menu..